# How to clear FormData() after submitting

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, form-data

I developed a file input. When selecting that file a function is executed that detects the file and sends it to a service.

My problem is that the format always absorbs all selected files and never cleans. That is, if you select 2 images and later delete one of them, I get 1, but if after deleting one image, insert another one ... I will have 3 and not two (there should be 2 because one of them has been deleted). The problem is that the formdata is always storing everything.

Is there a way to clear formadata whenever a file is inserted?

[Example - Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iw6v5y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**code**

```
  <input type="file" id="files" (change)="Add($event)">

  formData1 = new FormData();

 Add(event) {
    var anex = event.target.files;

    for (let index = 0; index < anex.length; index++) {
          this.formData1.append('file', anex[index]);
        }  

        this.sendfiles()
  }

  sendfiles(){
    console.log("Clear formdata();")
    console.log(this.formData1)
  }
```

Comment: Can you do something like this in the `Add(event)`. `if (this.formData1.get('file')) {
      this.formData1.delete('file');
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear your formData as a new instance before adding new files.

```
 Add(event) {
    var anex = event.target.files;
    // Clear form data before appending new ones
    this.formData1 = new FormData();

    for (let index = 0; index < anex.length; index++) {
          this.formData1.append('file', anex[index]);
        }  

        this.sendfiles()
  }
```